# How to silently call a URL in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata

What is the best way to silently call a URL

My current approach is to do the following:

```
NSData *dummyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

However, I know that the server returns a 1x1 Pixel gif image. So maybe there is a way that does not affect the memory usage, or otherwise better suitable for the purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: If data is transferred, memory is used. You're talking about just a few dozen bytes here, so what do you think is a problem here?

Comment: This is true. Technically I only want to call the url without interpreting what comes back from the server (in my case the gif image).

Comment: @AmitVyawahare why include a very large framework just for a simple HTTP request?

Comment: Why would you fetch it if you didn't want to do anything with it?

Comment: @Paul.s i am half agree with you but its not about the  very large framework. Its about how efficiently you get your data. He can cache it and do very good things with this framework.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare if the OP needed that functionality then great, although that framework is no longer maintained and the original author himself recommends not using it for any new projects in his blog post [request release](http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release];). Therefore I would say it's a pretty bad start.

Comment: @Paul.s thank you for the information. I don't know this. Do you know any similar framework i can use then for my future project ?

Comment: @AmitVyawahare You would have to look into that yourself and weigh up the different options. There are a few mentioned at the bottom of that blog post.

Comment: @Paul.s i think they removed that post from the website. I am not able to see that webpage.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare nope it's still there SO is messing with the formatting just go to http://allseeing-i.com/ and look down the right hand side for [request release]; blog post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem with `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is that is a synchronous download. This means the thread blocks until the download has finished. This is a problem if the connection is slow or the server cannot be reached, it blocks until a timeout occurs. If you do this on the main thread and it blocks for longer than about 0.2 seconds your user will notice that the UI is not responding during that time.

It's almost always better to do an asynchronous download using `NSURLConnection` as this won't block your thread.

See Apple's [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) on how to implement an asynchronous download. It's more typing than your one-liner but isn't complicated. You might want to use [[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a). If you're using the more "traditional" `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` or `initWithRequest:delegate:` (as described in the previously mentioned guide), just don't implement the `connection:didReceiveData:` delegate method to ignore the downloaded data.